# Cwd of a process started from hard link path

Tags: linux, xfs, hardlink

I have an app which is starting by path which contains a folder which is hard link.
If I look for process current working directory it is same as source of a hard link.
The main problem is that app has relative path for writing logs and etc. So logs are written to a relative path of the original path.
Is it possible for process to consider it's logical path as cwd?